# fill NaN with values of a similar row

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has these 2 columns: "reach" and "height". the column "reach" has a lot of missing value. But the column 'height' have all the value needed. What I see is that reach is often a function of height. Therefore, for the rows with NaN, I want to look at the height, then find another row with the same "height" and that has "reach" available, then copy this value to the 1 with missing value

| name | SApM | SLpM | height | reach | record | stance | strAcc | strDef | subAvg | tdAcc | tdAvg | tdDef | weight | born_year | win | lose | draw | nc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Justin Frazier | 6.11 | 1.11 | 6' 0" | 75 | 10-3-0 | Southpaw | 0.66 | 0.04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 265 | 1989 | 10 | 3 | 0 |  |
| Gleidson Cutis | 8.28 | 2.99 | 5' 9" | nan | 7-4-0 | Orthodox | 0.52 | 0.59 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 155 | 1989 | 7 | 4 | 0 |  |
| Xavier Foupa-Pokam | 2.5 | 1.47 | 6' 1" | nan | 32-22-0 | Open Stance | 0.43 | 0.49 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.16 | 185 | 1982 | 32 | 22 | 0 |  |
| Mirko Filipovic | 1.89 | 2.11 | 6' 2" | 73 | 35-11-2-(1 NC) | Southpaw | 0.5 | 0.63 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.19 | 0.78 | 230 | 1974 | 35 | 11 | 2 | 1 |
| Jordan Johnson | 2.64 | 3.45 | 6' 2" | 79 | 10-0-0 | Orthodox | 0.47 | 0.53 | 1.2 | 0.42 | 3.25 | 1 | 205 | 1988 | 10 | 0 | 0 |  |
| Martin Kampmann | 3.28 | 3.22 | 6' 0" | 72 | 20-7-0 | Orthodox | 0.42 | 0.62 | 2 | 0.41 | 1.86 | 0.78 | 170 | 1982 | 20 | 7 | 0 |  |
| Darren Elkins | 3.05 | 3.46 | 5' 10" | 71 | 27-9-0 | Orthodox | 0.38 | 0.52 | 1.1 | 0.33 | 2.67 | 0.56 | 145 | 1984 | 27 | 9 | 0 |  |
| Austen Lane | 6.32 | 5.26 | 6' 6" | nan | 2-1-0 | Orthodox | 0.35 | 0.6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 245 | 1987 | 2 | 1 | 0 |  |
| Rachael Ostovich | 3.97 | 2.54 | 5' 3" | 62 | 4-6-0 | Orthodox | 0.43 | 0.57 | 0.8 | 0.83 | 2.03 | 0.66 | 125 | 1991 | 4 | 6 | 0 |  |
| Travis Lutter | 2.42 | 0.41 | 5' 11" | 75 | 10-6-0 | Orthodox | 0.32 | 0.42 | 0.7 | 0.24 | 1.95 | 0.3 | 185 | 1973 | 10 | 6 | 0 |  |
| Tom Murphy | 0.17 | 2.5 | 6' 2" | nan | 8-0-0 | Southpaw | 0.71 | 0.84 | 2.5 | 0.85 | 7.51 | 0 | 227 | 1974 | 8 | 0 | 0 |  |
| Darrell Montague | 5.38 | 1.92 | 5' 6" | 67 | 13-5-0 | Southpaw | 0.25 | 0.52 | 1.4 | 0.25 | 0.72 | 0.33 | 125 | 1987 | 13 | 5 | 0 |  |
| Lauren Murphy | 4.25 | 3.95 | 5' 5" | 67 | 15-4-0 | Orthodox | 0.4 | 0.61 | 0.1 | 0.34 | 1.16 | 0.7 | 125 | 1983 | 15 | 4 | 0 |  |
| Bill Mahood | 3.59 | 1.54 | 6' 3" | nan | 20-7-1-(1 NC) | Orthodox | 0.85 | 0.17 | 3.9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 200 | 1967 | 20 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| Nate Marquardt | 2.32 | 2.71 | 6' 0" | 74 | 35-19-2 | Orthodox | 0.49 | 0.55 | 0.8 | 0.51 | 1.87 | 0.7 | 185 | 1979 | 35 | 19 | 2 |  |
| Mike Polchlopek | 1.33 | 2 | 6' 4" | nan | 1-1-0 | Orthodox | 0.38 | 0.57 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 285 | 1965 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  |
| Harvey Park | 7.21 | 3.77 | 6' 0" | 70 | 12-3-0 | Orthodox | 0.5 | 0.33 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 155 | 1986 | 12 | 3 | 0 |  |
| Junyong Park | 3.17 | 4.37 | 5' 10" | 73 | 13-4-0 | Orthodox | 0.47 | 0.58 | 0.6 | 0.57 | 3.02 | 0.46 | 185 | 1991 | 13 | 4 | 0 |  |
| Ricco Rodriguez | 1.15 | 1.85 | 6' 4" | nan | 53-25-0-(1 NC) | Orthodox | 0.51 | 0.61 | 1 | 0.39 | 2.3 | 0.4 | 265 | 1977 | 53 | 25 | 0 | 1 |
| Aaron Riley | 3.78 | 3.45 | 5' 8" | 69 | 30-14-1 | Southpaw | 0.34 | 0.61 | 0.1 | 0.34 | 1.18 | 0.6 | 155 | 1980 | 30 | 14 | 1 |  |

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I have put in the dataframe in markdown format. This is just part of the dataframe. I am sure that there is a similar height with reach data available for every NaN

Comment: Okay, but what's similar? The closest height that has a reach? What if there are two heights that are equally close with the different reaches? What about a cutoff of how far away the closest other height may be? What about linear interpolation?

Comment: Yes those are some good questions. To which I have to admit I don't know what would be the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a height reference dataframe with [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and fetch the first non-NaN entry of a height (if any) by [`.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), as follows:

```
height_ref = df.groupby('height')['reach'].first()


height
5' 10"    71.0
5' 11"    75.0
5' 3"     62.0
5' 5"     67.0
5' 6"     67.0
5' 8"     69.0
5' 9"      NaN
6' 0"     75.0
6' 1"      NaN
6' 2"     73.0
6' 3"      NaN
6' 4"      NaN
6' 6"      NaN
Name: reach, dtype: float64
```

Then, you can fill up the `NaN` values of column `reach` by looking up the height reference dataframe by [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and use [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill-up values, as follows:

```
df['reach2'] = df['reach'].fillna(df['height'].map(height_ref))
```

For demo purpose, I update to a new column `reach2`.  You can overwrite the original column `reach` as appropriate.

**Result:**

```
print(df[['height', 'reach', 'reach2']])


    height  reach  reach2
0    6' 0"   75.0    75.0
1    5' 9"    NaN     NaN
2    6' 1"    NaN     NaN
3    6' 2"   73.0    73.0
4    6' 2"   79.0    79.0
5    6' 0"   72.0    72.0
6   5' 10"   71.0    71.0
7    6' 6"    NaN     NaN
8    5' 3"   62.0    62.0
9   5' 11"   75.0    75.0
10   6' 2"    NaN    73.0      <=======  filled up with referenced height from other row
11   5' 6"   67.0    67.0
12   5' 5"   67.0    67.0
13   6' 3"    NaN     NaN
14   6' 0"   74.0    74.0
15   6' 4"    NaN     NaN
16   6' 0"   70.0    70.0
17  5' 10"   73.0    73.0
18   6' 4"    NaN     NaN
19   5' 8"   69.0    69.0
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works exactly the way I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I think that a method does not exist to do that in a simple step.
If i were in your shoes I would:

1. Create a support dataset made up of `height|reach` fully populated, in which I would store my best guess values
2. Join the support dataframe with the existing ones, using `height` as key
3. Coalesce the values where `NaN` appears: `df.reach = df.reach.fillna(df.from_support_dataset_height)`